Getting the nearest value of a column with time shift in python
I have a dataframe with a datetime (with milisseconds) as index and a price column. I want to create a new column with the nearest price from the row 20s earlier. For example:
Data Hora
2024-02-01 10:03:39.483   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:40.540   1.900
2024-02-01 10:03:41.550   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:43.563   1.890
2024-02-01 10:03:45.567   1.870
2024-02-01 10:03:45.583   1.890
2024-02-01 10:03:46.590   1.900
2024-02-01 10:03:48.620   1.930
2024-02-01 10:03:50.627   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:51.630   1.890
2024-02-01 10:03:53.647   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:55.753   1.900
2024-02-01 10:03:59.367   1.890
2024-02-01 10:04:02.497   1.910
2024-02-01 10:04:04.543   1.890
2024-02-01 10:04:05.550   1.860
2024-02-01 10:04:07.577   1.840
2024-02-01 10:04:08.157   1.850
2024-02-01 10:04:10.197   1.880
2024-02-01 10:04:11.887   1.910
2024-02-01 10:04:13.163   1.920

Edit:
Hello @mozway, I want to get the price that is closest to the price of the 20s earlier row.
Expected Output:

2024-02-01 10:03:39.483   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:40.540   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:41.550   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:43.563   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:45.567   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:45.583   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:46.590   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:48.620   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:50.627   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:51.630   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:53.647   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:55.753   1.880
2024-02-01 10:03:59.367   1.880
2024-02-01 10:04:02.497   1.880
2024-02-01 10:04:04.543   1.870


What do you mean by the "nearest price"? The one with the least price difference? Can you provide the explicit output for clarity?

Updated in the question @mozway

I don't see any update

Loaded here @mozway

Please break down the logic? For example, why do you get 1.870 for 10:04:04.543?

I'm sorry, the expected output would be 1.890 because 10:04:04.543 - 20s = 10:03:44.543, in which the nearest time is 2024-02-01 10:03:43.563 that has the price of 1.890

I see, then it's a merge_asof see below

If you want the price at the time closest to -20s, use a merge_asof:
df['Data Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data Hora'])

df['closest_price_20s'] = (pd
   .merge_asof(df['Data Hora'].sub(pd.Timedelta('20s')).rename('dh'),
               df['Data Hora'],
               left_on='dh', right_on='Data Hora', direction='nearest',
               # tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s') # uncomment to set a tolerance
              )['Data Hora']
   .map(df.set_index('Data Hora')['Price'])
)

Output:
                 Data Hora  Price  closest_price_20s
0  2024-02-01 10:03:39.483   1.88               1.88
1  2024-02-01 10:03:40.540   1.90               1.88
2  2024-02-01 10:03:41.550   1.88               1.88
3  2024-02-01 10:03:43.563   1.89               1.88
4  2024-02-01 10:03:45.567   1.87               1.88
5  2024-02-01 10:03:45.583   1.89               1.88
6  2024-02-01 10:03:46.590   1.90               1.88
7  2024-02-01 10:03:48.620   1.93               1.88
8  2024-02-01 10:03:50.627   1.88               1.88
9  2024-02-01 10:03:51.630   1.89               1.88
10 2024-02-01 10:03:53.647   1.88               1.88
11 2024-02-01 10:03:55.753   1.90               1.88
12 2024-02-01 10:03:59.367   1.89               1.88
13 2024-02-01 10:04:02.497   1.91               1.88
14 2024-02-01 10:04:04.543   1.89               1.89
15 2024-02-01 10:04:05.550   1.86               1.87
16 2024-02-01 10:04:07.577   1.84               1.90
17 2024-02-01 10:04:08.157   1.85               1.93
18 2024-02-01 10:04:10.197   1.88               1.88
19 2024-02-01 10:04:11.887   1.91               1.89
20 2024-02-01 10:04:13.163   1.92               1.88


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'date': [
        '1990-02-01 10:03:39.483',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:40.540',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:41.550',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:43.563',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:45.567',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:45.583',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:46.590',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:48.620',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:50.627',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:51.630',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:53.647',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:55.753',
        '1990-02-01 10:03:59.367',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:02.497',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:04.543',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:05.550',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:07.577',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:08.157',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:10.197',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:11.887',
        '1990-02-01 10:04:13.163'
    ],
    'price': [
        1.880, 1.900, 1.880, 1.890, 1.870, 1.890, 1.900, 1.930,
        1.880, 1.890, 1.880, 1.900, 1.890, 1.910, 1.890, 1.860,
        1.840, 1.850, 1.880, 1.910, 1.920
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Convert datetime index to Unix timestamps (in seconds)
timestamps = df.index.astype(np.int64) // 10**9

# Shift by 20 seconds
shifted_timestamps = timestamps - 20

# Find the index of the closest earlier timestamp using np.searchsorted
indices = np.searchsorted(timestamps, shifted_timestamps, side='right') - 1

# Ensure indices are valid (i.e., not out of bounds)
valid_indices = np.where(indices >= 0, indices, 0)

# Use the found indices to get the prices 20 seconds earlier
df['Price_20s_earlier'] = df['price'].values[valid_indices]

print(df)
'''
                        price  Price_20s_earlier
date                                             
1990-02-01 10:03:39.483   1.88               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:40.540   1.90               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:41.550   1.88               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:43.563   1.89               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:45.567   1.87               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:45.583   1.89               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:46.590   1.90               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:48.620   1.93               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:50.627   1.88               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:51.630   1.89               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:53.647   1.88               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:55.753   1.90               1.88
1990-02-01 10:03:59.367   1.89               1.88
1990-02-01 10:04:02.497   1.91               1.88
1990-02-01 10:04:04.543   1.89               1.89
1990-02-01 10:04:05.550   1.86               1.89
1990-02-01 10:04:07.577   1.84               1.90
1990-02-01 10:04:08.157   1.85               1.93
1990-02-01 10:04:10.197   1.88               1.88
1990-02-01 10:04:11.887   1.91               1.89
1990-02-01 10:04:13.163   1.92               1.88

'''

